# Dynamic creation of html elements in jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to create html elements dynamically but when i select the input type from drop down menu and hit create nothing is happening.WHat am i doing wrong?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
            $("#create").click(function(){
                var name = $("#name").val();
                var id = $("#id").val();
                var value = $("#value").val();
                //var elementtocreate = $("#elementtocreate option: selected").text();
                var elementtocreate = $("#elementtocreate").val();
                console.log(name+id+value+elementtocreate);

                var div = $(document.createElement(elementtocreate));
                $("#registrationform").html(div);
                $('#registrationform').html($(div, {class: id}));


            });

        });
```

HTML part :

```
<div id="registrationdiv">
        <center>        
            <form id="registrationform" >   
            </form>
        </center>           
    </div>
```

Comment: The [`.html()`](https://api.jquery.com/html/#html2) function only takes a string of HTML to set as HTML content, not a jQuery object (which is what is contained in the `div` variable).

Answer (score 1):

use `$(document.createElement('div'));` to create HTML element.

```
$("html tags").appendTo("where you want to add")
```